# Adding fade effects to img slider - pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

so, I know that jQuery makes this super easy, but I'd like to figure out how to do this **without** a js library. How can I incorporate a fade-in/out effect as the images in this slider change? I know you can alter the opacity using dot notation, I just can't figure out the logic of it all.

```
var myImg = document.querySelector('.imgSlot'),
  myImgArray = ["images/x.jpg", "images/y.jpg", "images/z.jpg", "images/abc.jpg"],
  imgIndex = 0,
  varTimerSpeed = 4000,
  intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImg, varTimerSpeed);

function changeImg() {
  myImg.setAttribute('src', myImgArray[imgIndex]);
  imgIndex++;
   if ( imgIndex >= myImgArray.length) {
        imgIndex = 0;
  }
};
```

Any advice would be much appreciated,

David

Answer (score 0):

You do this by using animation library. It works using setTimeout or setInterval functions to apply changes to objects's style every few milliseconds resulting in an animation.
For instance:

```
function moveElementToRight(el) {
    setInterval(function() {
       el.style.marginLeft = el.style.marginLeft + 10 //increase marginLeft by 10
    }),20) //every 20 milliseconds
}
```

Some basic logic:

```
var interval = 20 //milliseconds. Each 20 milliseconds = new frame.
var duration = 500 //milliseconds. Total time for the animation
var frames = Math.ceil(duration/interval) // frames count for the animation
```

You can use this values with an easing function which will return a value for the current frame by passing (interval*i++ , from_value, to_value, duration); Here "i" is obtain by looping frames count. From_value and to_value are element's style start value and respectively element's style end value (this may be applied for opacity too, which will result in fading effect).

This is very rough example but this is the main principle. For easing effects you can use easing functions. Here are some:

```
    easeInQuad: function (t, b, c, d) {
        return c*(t/=d)*t + b;
    },
    easeOutQuad: function (t, b, c, d) {
        return -c *(t/=d)*(t-2) + b;
    },
    easeInOutQuad: function (t, b, c, d) {
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
        return -c/2 * ((--t)*(t-2) - 1) + b;
    },
    easeOutCubic: function (t, b, c, d) {
        return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t + 1) + b;
    },
    easeInOutCubic: function (t, b, c, d) {
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t + b;
        return c/2*((t-=2)*t*t + 2) + b;
    },
    easeInQuart: function (t, b, c, d) {
        return c*(t/=d)*t*t*t + b;
    },
    easeOutQuart: function (t, b, c, d) {
        return -c * ((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t - 1) + b;
    },
    easeInOutQuart: function (t, b, c, d) {
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t*t + b;
        return -c/2 * ((t-=2)*t*t*t - 2) + b;
    },
    easeInQuint: function (t, b, c, d) {
        return c*(t/=d)*t*t*t*t + b;
    },
    easeOutQuint: function (t, b, c, d) {
        return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t*t + 1) + b;
    },
    easeInOutQuint: function (t, b, c, d) {
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t*t*t + b;
        return c/2*((t-=2)*t*t*t*t + 2) + b;
    },
    easeInSine: function (t, b, c, d) {
        return -c * Math.cos(t/d * (Math.PI/2)) + c + b;
    },
    easeOutSine: function (t, b, c, d) {
        return c * Math.sin(t/d * (Math.PI/2)) + b;
    },
    easeInOutSine: function (t, b, c, d) {
        return -c/2 * (Math.cos(Math.PI*t/d) - 1) + b;
    },
    easeInExpo: function (t, b, c, d) {
        return (t==0) ? b : c * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t/d - 1)) + b;
    },
    easeOutExpo: function (t, b, c, d) {
        return (t==d) ? b+c : c * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * t/d) + 1) + b;
    },
    easeInOutExpo: function (t, b, c, d) {
        if (t==0) return b;
        if (t==d) return b+c;
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2 * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t - 1)) + b;
        return c/2 * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * --t) + 2) + b;
    },
    easeInCirc: function (t, b, c, d) {
        return -c * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t/=d)*t) - 1) + b;
    },
    easeOutCirc: function (t, b, c, d) {
        return c * Math.sqrt(1 - (t=t/d-1)*t) + b;
    },
    easeInOutCirc:function (t, b, c, d) {
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return -c/2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - t*t) - 1) + b;
        return c/2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t-=2)*t) + 1) + b;
    },
    //a: amplitude (optional), p: period (optional)
    easeInElastic: function (t, b, c, d, a, p) {
        if (t===0) {return b;}
        if ((t/=d)==1) {return b+c;}
        if (!p) {p=d*0.3;}
        var s;
        if (a < Math.abs(c)) {
            a=c;
            s=p/4;
        }else {
            a=Math.abs(c);
            s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin(c/a);
        }
        return -(a*Math.pow(2,10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )) + b;
    },
    easeOutElastic: function (t, b, c, d, a, p) {
        if (t===0) return b;
        if ((t/=d)==1) return b+c;
        if (!p) p=d*0.3;
        var s;
        if (a < Math.abs(c)) {
            a=c;
            s=p/4;
        }else {
            a=Math.abs(c);
            s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
        }
        return a*Math.pow(2,-10*t) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p ) + c + b;
    },
    easeInOutElastic: function (t, b, c, d, a, p) {
        if (t===0) return b;
        if ((t/=d/2)==2) return b+c;
        if (!p) p=d*(0.3*1.5);
        var s;
        if (a < Math.abs(c)) {
            a=c;
            s=p/4;
        }else {
            a=Math.abs(c);
            s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
        }
        if (t < 1) {
            return -0.5*(a*Math.pow(2,10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )) + b;
        }
        return a*Math.pow(2,-10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )*0.5 + c + b;
    },
    easeInBack: function (t, b, c, d, s) {
        if (s === undefined) s = 1.70158;
        return c*(t/=d)*t*((s+1)*t - s) + b;
    },
    easeOutBack: function (t, b, c, d, s) {
        if (s === undefined) s = 1.70158;
        return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*((s+1)*t + s) + 1) + b;
    },
    easeInOutBack: function (t, b, c, d, s) {
        if (s === undefined) s = 1.70158;
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*(t*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t - s)) + b;
        return c/2*((t-=2)*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t + s) + 2) + b;
    },
    easeInBounce: function (t, b, c, d) {
        return c - this.easeOutBounce (d-t, 0, c, d) + b;
    },
    easeOutBounce: function (t, b, c, d) {
        if ((t/=d) < (1/2.75)) {
            return c*(7.5625*t*t) + b;
        } else if (t < (2/2.75)) {
            return c*(7.5625*(t-=(1.5/2.75))*t + 0.75) + b;
        } else if (t < (2.5/2.75)) {
            return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.25/2.75))*t + 0.9375) + b;
        } else {
            return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.625/2.75))*t + 0.984375) + b;
        }
    },
    easeInOutBounce: function (t, b, c, d) {
        if (t < d/2) return this.easeInBounce (t*2, 0, c, d) * 0.5 + b;
        return this.easeOutBounce (t*2-d, 0, c, d) * 0.5 + c*0.5 + b;
    }
```

Untested example:

```
function animate(element, property, start, end, interval, duration) {
    var frames = Math.ceil(duration/interval);
    for(i=0;i<=frames;i++) {
       (function(f){
           setTimeout(function() {
              element.style[property] = easing_function_from_above(interval*f, start, end,   duration);
           }, interval);
       })(i);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a good question. It certainly helped me learn alot. Without further ado, here's what I came up with:

**Note**: This is for fading only, this wouldn't help with other style animations

```
var fade = function (elementInDocument, fadeTo, amountOfTime) {
    var start = new Date().getTime(), //start with the beginning time
        getOpacity = function () {
            //returns the current opacity of the given element
            var cs = window.getComputedStyle(elementInDocument),
                co = cs.getPropertyValue('opacity');
            return parseFloat(co, 10); //getPropertyValue returns a string, 
                                       //so you need to float it
        },
        startingOpacity = getOpacity(), //the beginning opacity of the element
        diff = fadeTo - startingOpacity, //the difference between what you want the opacity to be 
                                         //and the beginning opacity
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            var co = getOpacity(), //start by getting the current opacity (each interval)
                runTime = new Date().getTime() - start, //the amount of time the function has run
                progress = runTime / amountOfTime; //the progress of the function

            if (progress >= 1) {
                clearInterval(timer); //stop the function because we have completed fade
            }
            //takes the beginning opacity and adds it to the product of the difference (diff) 
            //and progress of the function 
            elementInDocument.style.opacity = startingOpacity + (diff * progress); 
        }, 10);
};

//Then to call it
fade(document.getElementById("someElement"), .6, 3000);
```

I tried to explain in as much detail as I could.

Here's a fiddle with some test cases: http://jsfiddle.net/9U9h8/4/

**Another important note**: This isn't cross-browser, especially on the older ones (looking at you IE<9)

Answer (score -1):

I know you have asked for pure JavaScript but it would be better if you try using jQuery as jQuery can handle the cross-browser compatibility itself.

You can try something like this:

```
$("#"+elem).fadeOut(1000, function () {
    var img = imgArr[currIndex];
    $("#"+elem).attr("src",img);
    $("#"+elem).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

It makes use of jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut mechanism which controls the transparency.
Check the working example below.

[Image Slider using pure jQuery and without any plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/anubhavranjan/JS8Q9/)